# How to receive Android Intent from Zebra TC21 Scanner in Delphi 10.4.1 application

Tags: delphi, android-intent

I'm developing an Android app with Delphi 10.4.1 to deploy on a Zebra TC21. I'm trying to receive a barcode from DataWedge intent and the HandleIntentAction in my app doesn't fired. Zebra TC21 scanner configuration: Android 10, DataWedge version 8.2.60. I read some articles about receiving intents in Delphi, Embarcadero sample, DataWedge configuration demos and still I can't solve the problem. Can someone help me please?

"MyTest" application (pl.dplodz.MyTest):

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var AppEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, AppEventService) then
    AppEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent);
  // Register the type of intent action that we want to be able to receive.
  // Note: A corresponding <action> tag must also exist in the <intent-filter> section of AndroidManifest.template.xml.
  MainActivity.RegisterIntentAction(StringToJString('pl.dplodz.ACTION'));
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedNotification, HandleActivityMessage);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': AppStarted');
end;

procedure TMainForm.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': HandleActivityMessage Fired');
  if M is TMessageReceivedNotification then
    HandleIntentAction(TMessageReceivedNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TMainForm.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
var StartupIntent: JIntent;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': HandleAppEvent Fired');
  Result := False;
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.BecameActive then
  begin
    StartupIntent := MainActivity.getIntent;
    if StartupIntent <> nil then
      HandleIntentAction(StartupIntent);
  end;
end;

function TMainForm.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var Extras : JBundle;
    JStr   : JString;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': HandleIntentAction Fired');
  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then
  begin
    Extras := Data.getExtras;
    if Extras <> nil then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(JStringToString(Extras.getString(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT)))
    else
      Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': Extras = nil');
  end
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Now) + ': Data = nil');
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMainForm.CloseBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TMainForm.ClearMemoBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
end;
```

AndroidManifest.Template.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="%package%"
        android:versionCode="%versionCode%"
        android:versionName="%versionName%"
        android:installLocation="%installLocation%">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
    <%uses-permission%>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
        android:label="%label%" 
        android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
        android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
        android:icon="%icon%"
        android:theme="%theme%"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <%provider%>
        <%application-meta-data%>
        <%uses-libraries%>
        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="pl.dplodz.ACTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <%activity%>
        <%receivers%>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

My DataWedge profile configuration:

```
New profile: "MyTest", key configuration:
Profile Enabled
Associated Apps: "com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity | pl.dplodz.MyTest"
Barcode Input: Enabled
Keystroke Output: Disabled
Intent Output section:
  Intent action: pl.dplodz.ACTION
  Intent category: android.intent.category.DEFAULT  (btw. I tested with empty value - no changes)
  Intent delivery: Broadcast intent
  Component Information: [empty]
```

I hear a beep signal when scanning the code but nothing happens on the application. Where is the problem? In DataWedge config? In application?

Comment: If you're handling intents via RegisterIntentAction, you'll need to set Intent Delivery to Start Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, if you're handling intents via RegisterIntentAction, you'll need to set Intent Delivery to Start Activity.

You can however receive Broadcast Intents by creating a receiver in code. In this case, your app would need to be already running, however here is a possible implementation:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

type
  TDataWedgeDataEvent  = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Data: string) of object;

  TDataWedgeBroadcastListener = class(TJavaLocal, JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)
  private
    FReceiver: JBroadcastReceiver;
    FOnData: TDataWedgeDataEvent;
  public
    { JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener }
    procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnData: TDataWedgeDataEvent read FOnData write FOnData;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

{ TDataWedgeBroadcastListener }

constructor TDataWedgeBroadcastListener.Create;
var
  LIntentFilter: JIntentFilter;
begin
  inherited;
  FReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(Self);
  LIntentFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  LIntentFilter.addAction(StringToJString('pl.dplodz.ACTION')); // or whatever value the profile is configured for
  LIntentFilter.addCategory(StringToJString('android.intent.category.DEFAULT'));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.registerReceiver(FReceiver, LIntentFilter);
end;

destructor TDataWedgeBroadcastListener.Destroy;
begin
  TAndroidHelper.Context.unregisterReceiver(FReceiver);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDataWedgeBroadcastListener.onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  if (intent <> nil) and Assigned(FOnData) then
    FOnData(Self, JStringToString(intent.getStringExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.data_string'))));
end;
```

Create an instance of TDataWedgeBroadcastListener and hook up to the OnData event. Using this method, you do not need to set up an intent filter in the manifest

Comment: Hello Dave, I checked the proposed solutions (sending intent via StartActivity and via Broadcast with TDataWedgeBroadcastListener class) and both work great. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DPLodz If this answer works for you, can you mark it as "accepted"? Thanks!